# How to Loop through an xslt file and extracting paths

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to xslt processing and I have an xslt file that has like 6 of these nodes

```
 <xsl:element name="Object1">
        <xsl:for-each select="$RELATIONSHIP">
          <xsl:variable name="From" select="@xlink:from"/>
          <xsl:variable name="P_Role" select="@xlink:to"/>

          <xsl:for-each select="$PARTY">
            <xsl:variable name="$FirstName" select="./ns1:INDV/ns1:NAME/ns1:FirstName"/>
            <xsl:variable name="$MiddleName" select="./ns1:INDV/ns1:NAME/ns1:MiddleName"/>
            <xsl:variable name="$LastName" select="./ns1:INDV/ns1:NAME/ns1:LastName"/>

            <xsl:if test="contains(./ns1:ROLES/ns1:ROLE/@xlink:label,$P_Role) and contains($From,'ASSET')">

                <xsl:for-each select="$ASSET">
                  <xsl:if test="contains(@xlink:label,$From)">
                      <xsl:if test="./ns1:AST_DETAILS/ns1:AssetType='Stck' or ./ns1:AST_DETAILS/ns1:AssetType='Stck-Options' or ./ns1:AST_DETAILS/ns1:AssetType='Sav-Bond' or ./ns1:AST_DETAILS/ns1:AssetType='Bond' ">
                        <xsl:element name="Object1">
                          <xsl:element name="BOW_FNAME">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$FirstName"/>
                          </xsl:element>

                          <xsl:element name="BOW_LNAME">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$LastName"/>
                          </xsl:element>

                          <xsl:element name="COMPANY">
                            <xsl:value-of select="./ns1:HOLDER/ns1:NAME/ns1:FullName"/>
                          </xsl:element>
                          <xsl:element name="ASSTSNUMSTCKBOND">
                            <xsl:value-of select="./ns1:AST_DETAILS/ns1:StockBondCount"/>
                          </xsl:element>
                          <xsl:element name="ASSTSDESCRIPTION">
                            <xsl:value-of select="./ns1:AST_DETAILS/ns1:Description"/>
                          </xsl:element>
                          <xsl:element name="ASSTCOMPANYAMT">
                            <xsl:value-of select="./ns1:AST_DETAILS/ns1:AsstAmount"/>
                          </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:element>
                      </xsl:if>
                  </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>

            </xsl:if>

          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:element>
```

I want extract a condition and path and put it in a csv file ,I'd like to input an element name say Object1 and I will give me all its children and their xpath names, as an example

Condition:

```
./ns1:AST_DETAILS/ns1:AssetType='Stck' or ./ns1:AST_DETAILS/ns1:AssetType='Stck-Options' or ./ns1:AST_DETAILS/ns1:AssetType='Sav-Bond' or ./ns1:AST_DETAILS/ns1:AssetType='Bond
```

Path:
BOW_FNAME=$FirstName

Is there a parser I can use to achieve this ?
Do I have to write a utility to achieve this ?
Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to achieve. Is the XPath expression you have shown as the "condition" an input you want to start with and you want to find in the XSLT code you have? Or what does "extract" mean?

Comment: I'd like to extract it and put it in a csv file file

Comment: I'd like to input an element name say Object1 and I will give me all its children and their xpath names

Comment: Well, XSLT is XML so you can of course apply XSLT and XPath to an XSLT document and select e.g. `//xsl:element[@name = $element-name]` and its child elements with e.g. ``//xsl:element[@name = $element-name]/*`. I am not sure what you consider an "xpath name" or how that condition you have mentioned is part of the problem. And of course looking at XSLT in general the code could as well have used a literal result element name `Object1` instead of the constructor `xsl:element name="Object1"`, I am not sure whether you want to cover that as well.

Comment: Thanks but do you have link to an example to get me started?